# Methods to find API endpoints

Tags: rest, url, web-crawler, api-design

## API Exploration

*Although there are several questions that touch on the topic, none that I've been able to find address the core concept I'm trying to understand*

If the root structure of an API is know, let's imaginatively say `http://stackoverflow.com/api/service/` and we can successfully retrieve results from a know endpoint, let's say `http://stackoverflow.com/api/service/answers/?id=39234`, are there any methods, programmatic or otherwise, to identify *other* available endpoints?

#### Example

As an example, that's likely very source specific, googling the root url has revealed methods used in  tags in pages from the source. I'm interested in similar broadly applicable techniques that *may* work.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is not easy to answer your question in general, because there are a lot of different kinds of API's around in the world. For example:

- [Simple Object Access Protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOAP) for which the API is often described via [Web Services Description Language WSDL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Services_Description_Language) so you need to find the wsdl
- For RESTful API's there are some more API description languages [Overview of RESTful API Description Languages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overview_of_RESTful_API_Description_Languages) very famous is the [OpenAPI specification](https://swagger.io/specification/)
- Also sometime you have XML documents that describe API's like in AVM's FritzBox router - which can be downloaded from the device.
- Over the decades a lot more API descriptions have been developed like for [CORBA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Object_Request_Broker_Architecture)

So it always depends on what kind of API's you are interested in and knowing the description languages for them and then to find the descriptions via search engines like google or Shodan etc.